# Stretching the X or Y Axis on System.Graphics.DrawString

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, drawstring

Is there a way to stretch the X or Y axis when calling System.Graphics.DrawString? We are working on laying out a graphics image (which is actually going to be printed) where it would be nice to make a particular piece of text say 125% higher than it's normal height (while maintaining the same width). Is there a best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, Graphics.ScaleTransform() works fine as long as you use Graphics.DrawString() instead of TextRenderer.  Keep it modest, stretched text doesn't look that good.  125% ought to be okayish.

Comment: You can also use `Graphics.Save()` and `Graphics.Restore()` to backup and restore the original scaling, before the transform was made.